# Does Meteor webapp package works inside a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I have an WebApp.connectHandlers on my Meteor App, this handler verifies user authentication and then calls our CDN service using some dynamic authentication params.

My assets are using relative paths and when they hit the localhost:xxxxx/api/v2/files/... of the Meteor Cordova app the Angular routes are handling the request instead of the WebApp.

I need this handler to work inside my Cordova app, bit it is not happening. Does anyone know if it is possible?

The code:

```
function files(req, res) {
    // create authentication params for CDN
}
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/api/v2/files', (req, res) => files(req, res));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to use absolute URL's, or it just won't work. I think it's to do with the way hot code push works. There is a server that runs on the device, and it's not like the normal meteor process. Any relative paths will work for client side routing, but any server routes will not work unless they are absolute

Comment: I understand. The problem is that when I use the absolute path and the content is loaded from my production app domain, the production server doesn't see the user authenticated at the app, so i can't validate the user access.